# What does "Ruhebereich" (quiet zone) mean on German ICE trains?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

From the word "Ruhebereich" I would expect very quiet surroundings, but it has not been my experience. Passengers have no reservations about carrying on conversations, and families show up with small children.

So what should I expect from a quiet zone?

(Just for context; in Denmark the quiet zone on IC3 trains is silent - no talking, no children)

Comment: The primary meaning for [Ruhebereich - Englisch-Übersetzung – Linguee Wörterbuch](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/ruhebereich.html) is *rest/relaxation area*. You are mixing up **Ruhe** (rest) with **ruhig** (quite).

Comment: @Mark Johnson "Ruhe bitte" = "be quiet please" (Ruhe being a noun here). According to google image search, the stickers in the ICE actually also have "quiet zone", "Area del silencio" and other captions.

Comment: @Jan Nevertheless **Ruhebereich** (different noun, different expression) means **rest area** (not silent area). The DB notice is about avoiding noisy activities such as phone calls, ringtones, loud music. It says **nothing** about conversations.

Comment: Re *"in Denmark the quiet zone on IC3 trains is silent"*: Yes, usually, but not always (north bound in the middle of the day in Southern Denmark is particularly bad (mostly young people))

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Firstly, the explanation at bahn.de goes on "... oder sonstige lärmende Tätigkeiten nicht erwünscht." ("...or other noisy activities are not welcome"). Note also that they explicity request to not even hear loud music by *headphone*. Secondly, the "Psst"-icon with finger before the mouth very clearly depicts the German gesture for "stop talking [so loudly]/be silent". Both IMHO point very clearly to the meaning of this Ruhezohne including the low noise meaning of the word Ruhe. In any case, I'd argue that the German word Ruhe always has both connotations at the same time.

Comment: Which part of *stfu* is it that you don't understand? ;-)

Comment: On a more serious note, I have been reprimanded for conducting a loud conversation with my American partner for an extended period of time. I had not noticed we were in a *Ruhezone.* While quiet conversations can hardly be generally forbidden it is at least impolite to have lively conversations. What you can actually enforce is unclear but the gist of the designation is clear enough, and it boils down to being polite and considerate.

Comment: Me and my wife were traveling ICE from Düsseldorf to Würzburg, siting in Ruhebereich. We were talking in a low pitch, even then an old lady stopped us and said, this is Ruhebereich and we should not talk. In a way she pleaded and said she will get down in one and half hour. I felt if I am sitting in prison.

Answer (score 30):

Here's [what DB says about them](https://www.bahn.de/service/zug/handy_u_ruhebereiche):

> **Ruhebereich**
> Für Fahrgäste, die sich mehr Ruhe und Entspannung wünschen, haben wir unsere Ruhezonen optimiert. Sie befinden sich entweder in Abteilen, den ICE Lounges (Abteile hinter dem Fahrzeugführer) oder in kompletten Wagen.
> In diesem Bereich sind Handytelefonate, Klingeltöne, lautes Musikhören (auch via Kopfhörer) oder sonstige lärmende Tätigkeiten nicht erwünscht.

I couldn't find an equivalent page on the English site, so I'll do a rough translation myself:

> **Quiet zone**
> Our quiet zones are optimised for passengers who want more peace and quiet. They can be found in compartments, ICE lounges or in whole carriages. In these areas, phone calls, ringtones, loud music (including through headphones) and other loud activities are not welcome.

In principle, people shouldn't be making phone calls or having loud conversations in the Ruhebereich. It's not a *silent zone* and you shouldn't be surprised if passengers travelling together talk to each other, but it is a *quiet zone* and they should make an effort to keep their voices down while doing so.

If other passengers are being *noisy* (as opposed to just not being silent), you'd be well within your rights to point out where they are and ask them to adjust their volume/location. But I've not had to do this personally and couldn't tell you how it's likely to be received. I would note that I find the signage not especially clear (relatively small stickers in places you probably aren't paying attention to when trying to find seats, especially if doing so with small children in tow!). I can easily imagine that a lot of those not respecting the quiet zone simply don't realise they're in one at all.

Comment: The signs are now considerably larger than in the past (along the whole wall above the windows). And I repeatedly notice people asking other people to be more quiet / go outside for their phone call. In most of the cases this works fine and other passengers are actually grateful.

Comment: The signs are quite visible, but not so visible that one cannot miss them anyway. My experience is that not all people will be grateful when you point out the quiet zone, but most will be quiet(er) anyway. Obviously if the train is full and children just cannot keep quiet pointing out the quiet zone might be relatively futile. But it can work well if the train is less than half-full or so.

Comment: Iirc the entire train is separated into the two zones 'Ruhebereich' and 'Familienbereich'= family zone. So if you want to have a lengthy business conversation either live or on the phone it is essentially up to you whether you prioritize your personal interests and go to the quiet zone or prioritize other peoples interest and go to the family zone.

Comment: @Jan the people you point it out to are not grateful - but the other occupants of the quiet zone will. I was pretty annoyed to have to point out the rules of quiet zone to DB security personal. He gave me a bit of a stare but stopped playing on his smartphone with the sounds turned up.

Comment: Sorry, but us Germans just will sternly look at the loud people until they realize their erronous ways instead of directly confronting them.

Comment: I can only imagine, @Erik, the stern looks of several Germans would be enough to silence most anyone! :)

Comment: @quarague That's not true. The Familienbereich is something extra and not present in all the trains i've been on. Some have special family compartments, some a designated area in the undivided areas, some have none of those. The two other zones are the Ruhezone and the "Telefonzone", a telephone zone.

Comment: The reservation system also sometimes allocates seat reservations for families with small children into the quiet zone, without the family having asked for that.

Comment: @florian : Yes, and sometimes even without being able to see the zone information prior to boarding the train (happened to us, 2 parents and 3 children).

Comment: The primary concern of the DB "quiet zone" seems to be phone calls as evidenced by the crossed out cell phone as well as the contrasted "Handybereich" for cell phone use.

Comment: @user2705196: Funnily, some people seem to consider the quiet zone to be the only zone quiet enough for to make phone calls without too much background noise, so they use the quiet zone exactly for that purpose ;)

Answer (score 14):

Don't expect anything. It's sad but true; if I had time to think about it, I would probably come up with dozens of examples where Germans just ignore rules that are not enforced by anyone.

I'm not sure how many people are aware that there are "quiet zones" and "phone zones" on an ICE train. When you book a seat online, you get to choose which zone you want, I'm not sure about the machines at the station. But as you can board any ICE train without a reservation, I guess a large number of people never noticed the small stickers on the door. Most of them will be happy they found a seat no matter which zone.

Even if people were aware, I doubt it would make much of a difference. There will always be one person to ignore the quiet zone (knowingly or unknowingly), and instead of telling them to stop, a lot of Germans tend to let it go and instead start ignoring the quiet zone themselves. As a result, anyone coming in will not notice that they are in a quiet zone and also engage in conversations and stuff...

Comment: There is the option of speaking up. Saying *"This is a quiet zone."* and pointing at the sign is usually sufficient. Maybe they are just ignorant...Swedes! *Selbstjustiz* can work (may not be the right word). Alternatively, (discreetly) letting the conductor know about it (e.g., by hand signs, without saying anything), so they can enforce it.

Comment: "Handy", just like "beamer" and "public viewing" are German words that seem to be English but aren't used or understood outside of Germany.

Comment: @PeterMortensen In my experience, speaking up will work with about 20%. The other 80% will tell you to mind your own business in a more or less friendly way... _Selbstjustiz_ has a way stronger meaning than just speaking up, but I currently fail to find a good german word for what you mean (maybe because it's not a typical german thing to do?!?).

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks for the reminder. In theory, I know; in practice, I sometimes forget...